# Postgresql Sequelize search with one to many join

Tags: node.js, postgresql

New to postgresql and I am using node and Sequelize. I have a database with tables vehicles and photos:

```
¦Vehicles:
¦
¦ id     99
¦ make   Nissan
¦ model  Micra

¦Photos:
¦
¦ id            1      2
¦ photoUrl    xxx    yyy
¦ photoOrder    1      2
¦ vehicleId    99     99
```

What I am hoping for, on a search by vehicle id, is an output like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":99,
        "make":"Nisan",
        "model":"Micra",
        "photos":[
            {
                "photoOrder":1,
                "photoUrl":"xxx"
            },
            {
                "photoOrder":2,
                "photoUrl":"yyy"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The associations that I have are:

```
db.photos.belongsTo(db.vehicles);
db.vehicles.hasMany(db.photos);
```

I can add vehicles and add photos. When I retrieve a vehicle(s) I get the vehicle info but no photos:

```
export function findAll(req, res) {
    Vehicle.findAll()
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
           ...
        });
}
```

Have I got my associations correct and how do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the photos via the `getPhotos` function on the vehicles. If you want to eagerly load them then you need to do something like

```
Vehicle.findAll({
  include: Photos
})
```

Documentation here .. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#eager-loading-example

Comment: If you always always want photos.. you should look at scopes... https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. And I will have good look at scopes. Thanks also.